# Read file real time with while loop and trigger action on change

Tags: bash, linux

I want to read a file real time with a while loop that is being fed by the `stdout` of a process (`inotifywait`). The output could be multiple lines, but I as soon as I've found name of a specific file in a line, I want to discard all the other lines. How can you do that without breaking the while loop? I think my current code will be hard to maintain.

**What I want:**

```
 #!/bin/bash

 FILENAME=config.txt

 while read -r OUTPUT_DATE OUTPUT_FILE OUTPUT_EVENT; do

     # check if file name is found on line
     # grep -q will give me an exit code of 0
     # if file is found 
     echo "$OUTPUT_FILE" | grep -q "^$FILENAME"

     if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         # perform an action(restart nginx, for example)!
         # and discard the other lines but do no break loop
     fi
 done < <(inotifywait -m -e close_write --timefmt '%Y%m%d%H%M' --format '%T %f %e' ./)
```

[Depending on the texteditor](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Analysis-of-inotify-events-for-different-editors), `inotifywait` can emit multiple lines output for a single modified file, like:

```
201710092031 config.txt CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE <-- I was looking for config.txt so stop reading lines
201710092031 config.txt CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE
201710092031 .config.txt.edited CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE
```

**My current workaround:** (save date and time in hidden file and prevent update if multiple actions occur too fast after each other)

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=config.txt
FILENAME_EDITED=~/ahn/.$FILENAME.edited

while read -r OUTPUT_DATE OUTPUT_FILE OUTPUT_EVENT  
do    
    echo $OUTPUT_FILE | grep -q "^$FILENAME"

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        # if the date + time of changed file is similar to
        # the date + time in hidden file, or if hidden file
        # does not exist, perform action and update date+time
        # in hidden file
        if ( [ -f "$FILENAME_EDITED" ] && [ $( cat "$FILENAME_EDITED" ) != "$OUTPUT_DATE" ] ) || [ ! -f "$FILENAME_EDITED" ]; then
            echo Restart process etc.
        fi
    fi
done < <(inotifywait -m -e close_write --timefmt '%Y%m%d%H%M' --format '%T %f %e' ./)
```

Comment: Why not just set a variable to the timestamp?

Comment: @Barmar: thanks. If I would call the new variable $LATEST_TIMESTAMP, that shortens my second if clause from `[ -f "$FILENAME_EDITED" ] && [ $( cat "$FILENAME_EDITED" ) != "$OUTPUT_DATE" ] ) || [ ! -f "$FILENAME_EDITED" ]` to `[ $LATEST_TIMESTAMP -ne $OUTPUT_DATE ]` . Feel stupid for not having done that in the first place. I still wonder though if I could break out of this while loop without killing the inotifywait process.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. When the loop ends, it closes the pipe that reads from `inotifywait`. When `inotifywait` tries to write to the pipe, it gets an error.

Comment: You could run `inotifywait` in a background process, writing to a named pipe. Run another background process that has the pipe open for reading, but doesn't read from it, like `sleep 100000 < ~/ahn/.pipe`. Then you can redirect the input of your `while` loop to the pipe.